# Django Rest Framework + Django-Allauth Password Reset/Recovery

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth, password-recovery

I am trying to create a password recovery flow using Django Rest Framework and Django-Allauth.

Django-Allauth already does everything i need, my question is can i programatically call a django-allauth function or view from DRF that receives the email i want to reset and continues with the rest of the normal allauth flow (like creating the temporary tokens and sending the email to the client?

I don't see the point on having to rewrite all that code if one of the apps is doing everything i need. just need some help on how to "glue" them :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i figured it out

I added this to my DRF resource

```
@list_route(
    methods=['post'], permission_classes=[AllowAny],
    authentication_classes=[NoAuthentication]
)
def recover_password(self, request):
    if request.DATA.get('email'):
        # Lets be smart and reuse django-allauth password recovery system
        form = ResetPasswordForm({'email': request.DATA.get('email')})
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return Response(status=200)
    return Response(status=400)
```

Comment: To which file in DRF did you add this code? (e.g., settings.py within rest_framework?)

Comment: added it to the views.py

Comment: @psychok7 do you have this up on a repo somewhere I could take a look at?

Answer (score 5):

In case it helps, solved this problem by just created a new class to override the password serializer.

```
from rest_auth.serializers import PasswordResetSerializer
from allauth.account.forms import ResetPasswordForm

class PasswordSerializer (PasswordResetSerializer):
    password_reset_form_class = ResetPasswordForm
```

Then make sure to add this to your settings:

```
REST_AUTH_SERIALIZERS = {
    'PASSWORD_RESET_SERIALIZER': 'api.helpers.pwdreset.PasswordSerializer',
}
```

Comment: where did you create the new class?  Could you expand your solution please?

Comment: the new class was in the module "api.helpers.pwdreset" -- but it could be in any file as long as you use that path in the second piece.  The second bit is in your settings.py

Comment: I get this error: ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1). Any idea what might be the cause?